# Getting Autosys Job Status from Autosys CLI using Java

Tags: java, batch-file, autosys

I used batch file to fetch status of Autosys job from Autosys CLI. But I want to do the same in Java. I want to fetch the data for Automated mails.
I know the Runtime class can be used for executing external commands and used it for Powershell.
But I am not sure how to do the same with Autosys CLI. I would like to fetch the data for Automated mails.

```
SET SERVER1=xxxxxx    
SET AUTOSERV=xxxxx    
SET PATH=xxx   
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('autostatus -J xxxxjob') do set status=%%j
```

Comment: What does the code outputs?

Comment: For the above code, the status variable will save the status of the job.

Comment: May you put the content of `%status%` in your post?

Comment: The output is "SUCCESS"

Comment: May you please put it in your post?